Get VS Code to open a directory after connecting
I'm working over an SSH connection in VS Code. I only have one directory that I'm working in, so I'd like to just connect to it. But currently I need to

Connect the current window to host...
Open directory...
Navigate to the correct directory from $HOME

Is there a way to set Code so that for this machine, whenever I connect it just opens the same directory automatically?
